# Bind data to single words in a div with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, data-binding

I want to highlight some words in a text and bind them to my data, in order to be able to click on these words and change some variables in the scope.
I have a list of words in my data model and I have two views for the same data: a list and the text containing the words.

[image: Screenshot of the two views]

The list is easy to realize with `ng-repeat`: I can easily filter the list and handle clicks on the items through `ng-click`.

For the "text view" I didn't find any directive, so I realized it on my own, by breaking the text and wrapping them in spans to realize the colored background effect.
My problem is that I don't know **how to bind data to those spans**; moreover, they don't seem to belong to the angular context, thus ng-click and other directives won't work. 
How would you realize such a thing?

My goal is to click on "Queensland" on the document and expand the "Queensland" entry in the list. I currently do the same when the user clicks on the list entry, I expand it to show some details, by simply watching a variable on the scope with ng-show.

**Here's the pen**

http://codepen.io/mendaomn/pen/LpRxOL

**EDIT 1:** Ok, I've been caught by other issues, but now I'm back to this. I managed to solve it by creating a directive `reviewDoc`

```
 <div review-doc class="document"></div>
```

and in the directive, linking the scope to the element, in the link function

```
var underlinedText = highlightDocument(scope.data.document.text, scope.data.words, scope.filters.applyFilters);
var element = angular.element("<div>" + underlinedText + "</div>");
var test = $compile(element)(scope);
elt.html(test);
```

Now, in my `highlightDocument()` I basically go through the document's content, find the words and surround them with a `span` tag. Such a tag comes with a `ng-click` attribute that would allow filtering the table on the left basing on the bound word.

Here's the span definition:

```
var boundData = JSON.stringify(word);
var tag_open = '<span ng-click=\'filters.toggleTag(' + boundData + ', $event)\' ng-class=\'{"document-highlight--selected": filters.isTagSelected(' + boundData + ') && filters.isSynonym(' + boundData + ',' + string + ')}\' class="document-highlight--bold" >';
var tag_close = "</span>";
```

Where `boundData` is one of the objects that can also be seen in the table on the left. It seems to be working fine, but it's nasty and feels hacky to me, since in the HTML you end up inspecting such awesomeness:

```
<span ng-click="filters.toggleTag({"name":"Toads","class":"Animal","taxonomy":"GeoNat35","count":3,"score":0.87,"type":"Detected","offset":[{"firstchar":653,"lastchar":658},{"firstchar":787,"lastchar":792},{"firstchar":1103,"lastchar":1108}],"$$hashKey":"object:46"}, $event)" ng-class="{"document-highlight--selected": filters.isTagSelected({"name":"Toads","class":"Animal","taxonomy":"GeoNat35","count":3,"score":0.87,"type":"Detected","offset":[{"firstchar":653,"lastchar":658},{"firstchar":787,"lastchar":792},{"firstchar":1103,"lastchar":1108}],"$$hashKey":"object:46"}) && filters.isSynonym({"name":"Toads","class":"Animal","taxonomy":"GeoNat35","count":3,"score":0.87,"type":"Detected","offset":[{"firstchar":653,"lastchar":658},{"firstchar":787,"lastchar":792},{"firstchar":1103,"lastchar":1108}],"$$hashKey":"object:46"},"toads")}" class="document-highlight--bold">toads</span>
```

Would you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

in your "text view" directive add an attribute that is bound to a parent scope method something like:

```
<my-directive on-word-click="onWordClick(word)" ...>
```

Then in your directive make the ng-click on each highlighted word call the bound function with the word as argument.
There's a bit of trickiness in angular directives on how to pass arguments, but if you post your code and need some help, people on this thread will be able to help.

Comment: you're absolutely right, I'll prepare a pen on codepen to try to show what I'd like to obtain, but it's kind of hard since I didn't find a solution yet so I'm not sure what to show :)